# How can I stop an audio line from recording in another method?

Tags: java

Is there anyway I can stop the line from capturing (line.stop) inside the `stopCapture` method?

```
public class Ouvir extends NewJFrame{
    AudioFormat audioFormat;
    TargetDataLine targetDataLine;

    void captureAudio(){
        Stop.setEnabled(true);
        try{
            audioFormat = getAudioFormat();
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, audioFormat);
            TargetDataLine line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            line.open();
            line.start();
        }
        catch (LineUnavailableException e) {}
    }

    void stopCapture(){ 
    }

    private AudioFormat getAudioFormat(){
        float samplerate = 48000f;
        return new AudioFormat(samplerate,8,1,true,true);
    }
}
```

Comment: your question is unclear.

Comment: if(line != null)
         {
          line.stop();
          line.close();
         }
 
like this?

Comment: see answer. I've never used AudioFormat though, so can't make guarantees or promises.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want to call `line.stop();` or something to that effect in the `stopCapture()` method. If so, then the `TargetDataLine line` variable must be an instance field of your class and not a local variable. You'll also want to test for null before calling `stop()` on the field.

e.g.,

```
public class Ouvir extends NewJFrame{
    AudioFormat audioFormat;
    TargetDataLine targetDataLine;
    private TargetDataLine line; // **add this field**. It starts out  null

    void captureAudio(){
        Stop.setEnabled(true);
        try{
            audioFormat = getAudioFormat();
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, audioFormat);

            // change the code below 
            // TargetDataLine line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info); // from this
            line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);  // to this

            AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            line.open();
            line.start();
        }
        catch (LineUnavailableException e) {}
    }

    void stopCapture(){ 
        if (line != null && line.isRunning()) {
            // here you call your stop method, if one exists
            line.stop(); // ??? perhaps ???
            // perhaps this would need to be called within a try/catch block as well, not sure
        }
    }
```

side note: this looks dangerous:

```
catch (LineUnavailableException e) {}
```

You shouldn't ignore exceptions, but rather should handle them when they occur.

Other issues: this looks to be part of a Swing GUI, and if so, you probably will need to take Swing threading issues into account so that you don't have any long-running code blocking the Swing event thread, freezing your GUI.

Comment: what could occur in this case?
sorry for being so lost, it's a new field for me haha

Comment: @GabrielMendes: what could occur in *what* case? Do you mean the empty catch block? It means errors can occur during program run, and you will have no idea that they're occurring -- the programmer's equivalent of driving a car with your eyes closed. Definitely check out the [Exceptions Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

Comment: i meant to say what kind of error could happen in this specific case